# Prove that an open set G contained in the unit cube $E = [0, 1]^ n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is measurable according to Lebesgue

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

can you help me?
Prove that an open set G contained in the unit cube $E = [0, 1] ^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is measurable according to Lebesgue

I do not understand that how I should show it,
just that the open $(0,1)$ is measurable, right?
the upper and lower measurements must be the same, but how do I do that?

thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Start at the top. What is your definition of measurable?

Comment: @UmbertoP. A is measurable according to Lebesgue if, and only if,
for all ε> 0 there is a compact set $K ⊂ R^{k}$
and an open set $G ⊂ R^{k}$ such that
$K ⊂ A ⊂ G and µ (G \ K) <ε$ ? :c

Comment: Is $\mu$ the Lebesgue outer measure?